# How to add images to a tableview cell through stackview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I have a function that finds the number of stars that should be added to and adds to the stackview. The stackview is inside a table cell and thus displays the correct rating, which is retrieved from CoreData. However, the rating is not displaying.

the function ...

```
  func setRating(entry: Entry, ratingView: UIStackView) -> UIStackView{

    for _ in 0..<Int(entry.rating) {

        let image = UIImage(named:"ratingFilled")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)

        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)

        NSLayoutConstraint(item: image!, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: image!, attribute:.width, multiplier: 1.0, constant:0.0).isActive = true

        ratingView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
    }

    return ratingView
}
```

Tableview cell call...

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{ //creates rzeusable cell and assigns cell items

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    let entry = entries[indexPath.row]

    cell.nameLabel?.text = entry.restaurantName

    cell.ratingView = setRating(entry: entry, ratingView: cell.ratingView)

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a width constraint to either each `imageView` or the the `stackView` itself.

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: image!, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: image!, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
```

Also make sure to set `stackView` axis to horizontal

```
stackView.axis = .horizontal
```

Comment: stackview is in horizontal and I thought i have already set imageView frame to 20 by 20. After adding your constraint its still not working

Comment: you also need to add height constraint, check the edit

Comment: adding a constraint with the same 2 items is not meant to be, you need to add constraint with constant as shown above. let me know if that makes it for you.

Comment: it was something else haha i realized my "entry" variable had a problem that stored rating as 0. Thank you for the help tho Joze